# OneToOne relation always eager for envers

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, one-to-one, audit

I have problem with hibernate envers audit tool. My entity contains audited property with relation @OneToOne and it seems that envers always load data for this property even if it marked as FetchType.LAZY. So it seems that it ignore lazy load. For the others relations it seems that works correctly. Can anybody confirm this behavior or has any idea for some workaround/fix of this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using

```
 @MapsId
```

This way, you don’t even need a bidirectional association since you can always fetch the detail property entity by using the parent entity identifier.

This is article give a relative explanation and example on this
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/